# Expectation of $X^{T}CX$ ($E(X^{T}CX)$) where C is constant matrix

Tags: matrices, random-variables, expectation

Suppose $X$ is a random vector and C is a constant matrix. How do we compute $E(X^{T}CX)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$X^TCX=\sum_{i,j}c_{ij}X_iX_j\text{ so that }\mathsf E[X^TCX]=\sum_{i,j}c_{ij}\mathsf EX_iX_j$$

Comment: What if C is a symmetric matrix ?

Comment: The same expression with $c_{ij}=c_{ji}$ so you can slightly modify and write something like $\sum_ic_{ii}\mathsf EX_i^2+2\sum_{i<j}c_{ij}\mathsf EX_iX_j$.

Comment: Does $X^{T}CX$ have a chi-squared distribution ? I hope you don't mind the follow up question.

Comment: Not necessarily. That depends on the distribution of $X$ and also on $C$. I will not go deeper into this in comments on this answer. If you want more to know then just ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I see if X is normally distributed and C is a symmetric matrix($C=A^{T}A$ for some A), the expectation is basically the Euclidean norm of the gaussian random vector($||AX||$) which has a chi-squared distribution. Thanks again!